# Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server from external host connection

Tags: postgresql, psql, portforwarding

I have a postgresql server running on my ubuntu pc at home.

I have already set up the server to post-forward to accept external connections.

But for some reason, I can only connect to it on my local pc, I can't seem to connect to it from external connections.

Here are my settings for `/etc/postgresql/12/main/pg_hba.conf`,

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     password
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            password
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 password
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     password
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            password
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 password
```

Here are the settings for `/etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf`,

```
listen_addresses = '*'
port = 5432
```

I have set up my external port to be `2345`, and done the port forwarding on my router.

When I run, `psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -d postgres -U postgres`, I can connect to the server.

But when I run, `psql -h xxx.xx.xx.xx -p 2345 -d postgres -U postgres` (ip address hidden), I get the following error

```
psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: Operation timed out
        Is the server running on host "xxx.xx.xx.xx" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 2345?
```

I don't think there's anything wrong with my router either because I'm using it to forward SSH connections and I can connect from external connections fine.

What's wrong with my settings?

Comment: when on local can you connect using 0.0.0.0 or machine's IP?

Comment: in ipv4 section of configuration it is set to only allow connections from 127.0.0.1
`host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            password` try changing it to the public ip.

Comment: @TalhaJunaid I can connect using 0.0.0.0 from my local computer, but when i change 127.0.0.1 to the external IP address, both 0.0.0.0 and the external ip address doesnt work.

Comment: try setting ip to `0.0.0.0/0`

Comment: i can connect to 0.0.0.0, but i cant connect using the external ip and external port, I can tell that it's trying to connect, it doesnt immediately throw the error like if i use another port..

Comment: is your setting like ?
`host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            password`

Comment: yes its exactly like that

Comment: do i need to do something with iptables?

Comment: if you have configured those rules before then you might need to by default you don't have to. worth checking that out, also check using `netstat -lntu` which ports are opened on what level

Comment: ubuntu has a firewall right? maybe i need to open a port there or something

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223722/discussion-between-anarchy-and-talha-junaid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a conversation with @anarchy he had Uncomplicated Firewall (uwf) enabled.
adding a rule to the firewall worked.

To inspect check what ports are opened using network utility

```
netstat -lntu
```

To check if UFW is running

```
sudo uwf status
```

if it is enabled add the port you want to open

```
sudo ufw allow 22
```

and then reload firewall

```
sudo ufw reload
```